# FORTRAN compiler warning: obsolete arithmetic IF statement

Tags: gfortran

I have a gfortran error:

```
Warning: Obsolete: arithmetic IF statement at (1)
```

What does this mean? In the source (old source):

```
66 s12 = max(epsilon, s1 + s2)
c Then execution will go to label 13. Will this stop any further problems?
if (s12 - 1.0) 13, 13, 12
13 z = s1 / s12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arithmetic if is a peculiar feature of FORTRAN

it works as follows.

```
 IF (expr) label1, label2, label3
```

If the value of the expression is

```
less than 0, jump to label1 
equal to 0, jump to label2
greater than 0, jump to label3
```

In newer FORTRAN standards this feature is obsolete

In your code you can replace it with

```
      IF (s12 - 1.0 .gt. 0 ) GOTO 12
13    z = s1 / s12
```

Answer (score 0):

Check here:

http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/ch1-5.html

"The Arithmetic IF is considered harmful."

Your statement,

`if (s12 - 1.0) 13, 13, 12` is an Arithmetic IF, and is considered bad programming.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I changed them to the regular expression.                  if (s12 - 1.0 .LT. 0) then
                     GOTO 13
                
                 else if (s12 - 1.0 .EQ. 0) then
                     GOTO 13
                
                 elseif (s12 - 1.0 .GT. 0) then
                     GOTO 12
                 endif

Comment: Remember to choose by clicking the checkmark by one of the answers here if it in fact answered your question. Of course there's nothing wrong with not checking one if none of them answers well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Quoth [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_IF):

"..the Fortran statement defines three different branches depending on whether the result of an expression was negative, zero, or positive, in said order..."

"..was finally labeled obsolescent in Fortran 90."